# Copy rows to a new Sheet based on a value, times the value

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

I've seen a lot of answers to this questions but they seem not to work properly. I have this dataset in Sheet 1:

```
Animal 1 | Cat  | 5 | Male            
Animal 2 | Mouse| 3 | Female    
Animal 3 | Dog  | 1 | Male
```

And I want to get this on Sheet 2 by pressing a command button on Sheet 1:

```
Animal 1 | Cat  | 5 | Male
Animal 1 | Cat  | 5 | Male
Animal 1 | Cat  | 5 | Male
Animal 1 | Cat  | 5 | Male
Animal 1 | Cat  | 5 | Male
Animal 2 | Mouse| 3 | Female
Animal 2 | Mouse| 3 | Female
Animal 2 | Mouse| 3 | Female
Animal 3 | Dog  | 1 | Male
```

Keep in mind that this is a sample, my dataset as 40 columns and over 1500 rows, the value that i want to copy is in column C.

The work that i've done so far with the code was something like this:

```html
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    
    Dim currentRow As Long
    Dim currentNewSheetRow As Long: currentNewSheetRow = 1

    For currentRow = 1 To 1547 'The last row of your data
    Dim timesToDuplicate As Integer
    timesToDuplicate = CInt(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & currentRow).Value)
    
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To timesToDuplicate
        Sheet2.Range("A" & currentNewSheetRow).EntireRow.Value2 = Sheet1.Range("A" & currentRow).EntireRow.Value2
        Sheet2.Range("B" & currentNewSheetRow).EntireRow.Value2 = Sheet1.Range("B" & currentRow).EntireRow.Value2
        Sheet2.Range("C" & currentNewSheetRow).EntireRow.Value2 = Sheet1.Range("C" & currentRow).EntireRow.Value2
        Sheet2.Range("D" & currentNewSheetRow).EntireRow.Value2 = Sheet1.Range("D" & currentRow).EntireRow.Value2
        Sheet2.Range("E" & currentNewSheetRow).EntireRow.Value2 = Sheet1.Range("E" & currentRow).EntireRow.Value2
        Sheet2.Range("F" & currentNewSheetRow).EntireRow.Value2 = Sheet1.Range("F" & currentRow).EntireRow.Value2
        Sheet2.Range("G" & currentNewSheetRow).EntireRow.Value2 = Sheet1.Range("G" & currentRow).EntireRow.Value2
        Sheet2.Range("H" & currentNewSheetRow).EntireRow.Value2 = Sheet1.Range("H" & currentRow).EntireRow.Value2
        Sheet2.Range("I" & currentNewSheetRow).EntireRow.Value2 = Sheet1.Range("I" & currentRow).EntireRow.Value2
        Sheet2.Range("J" & currentNewSheetRow).EntireRow.Value2 = Sheet1.Range("J" & currentRow).EntireRow.Value2
        Sheet2.Range("K" & currentNewSheetRow).EntireRow.Value2 = Sheet1.Range("K" & currentRow).EntireRow.Value2
        'Continuous
        currentNewSheetRow = currentNewSheetRow + 1
    Next i
Next currentRow

End Sub
```

Thank You!

Comment: Don't understand what your question is?

Comment: My question is what is wrong with my code? I just want to build a Command Button that copys the intire row in sheet 1 to sheet 2, and i want that the number of times that the copy happens is equal to the cell value on that row in column C.

Comment: And what is the problem? Any errors raised or the code just don't do what you expected?

Comment: I get: Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range.

Comment: On which line the error occurs?

Comment: timesToDuplicate = CInt(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & currentRow).Value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Demo2()
    Dim lastRow As Long, lastColumn As Long, rowIndex As Long
    Dim srcSht As Worksheet, destSht As Worksheet
    Dim timesToDuplicate As Long, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Set srcSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet5")  'sheet with data
    Set destSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet6") 'output sheet

    lastRow = srcSht.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row      'last row with data
    lastColumn = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column   'number of columns

    rowIndex = 1
    For i = 1 To lastRow                                'loop for all the rows with data
        timesToDuplicate = srcSht.Cells(i, 3).Value     'get number of times row to be displayed
        For j = 1 To timesToDuplicate                   'loop for displaying row timesToDuplicate no. of times
            For k = 1 To lastColumn                     'loop of all columns
                destSht.Cells(rowIndex, k) = srcSht.Cells(i, k) 'display data
            Next k
            rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
        Next j
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```